Save a column to preserve a + in a column
I use a large SQL statement to generate data for XLSX, this includes the use of concats in at least one place to reformat phone numbers to strip spaces and add a +1, as is required for this XLSX.
SELECT ...
FROM 
    (SELECT ...
       case when p2.national_number is not null then concat('+1', p2.national_number) else p2.national_number end as PhoneNumber)

These results are returned as a string, transformed off Varchars elsewhere in the database.

This is run inside a collection where Laravel Excel handles it from here
return collect($receipts);

The issue is the generated XLSX saves this as a Number, and it interprets the text field as a number, treating the addition of + as a positive number

This is not what I intended. The plus sign must be present. I have attempted to use columnFormats() with the following settings, the same results persist.
public function columnFormats(): array
{
    return [
        'G' => NumberFormat::FORMAT_TEXT
    ];
}

Any recommendations on how to address this would be appreciated.

helps. on collect is string or int phone number key?

Returns as a string based on a dd()

I guess i'ts the plus sign that is giving bad format on xlsx. check this, put a ' in the beginning
